# How many spells does a Bard have at 20th level?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, bard

According to the bard grid they get 22 spells, but as a class feature they get to plunder 2 more spells from any class at 10, 14 and 18.  So does that mean they have a total (at level 20) of 22 spells or 28 spells?

I have looked around the net and found a few premade level 20 characters and lists of suggestions. The opinion on this subject seems to be split and I have no clue which it is anymore.

Answer (score 37):

Magical Secrets is a base bard ability that grants you two choices at level 10 , 14 and 18.

You are missing this important part of 'Magical Secrets'

> "....the chosen spells count as bard spells and are included in the number of spells known column of the bard table...."

So yes, **including** Magical Secrets, you know 22 spells at level 20.

The only exception to this rule is if you happen to be in the College of Lore, where you gain *Additional Magical Secrets* at level 6, which do NOT count against the number of spells known, which would grant you an actual total of 24 spells known at level 20.

Answer (score 14):

#### 22

> **Magical Secrets** ...The chosen spells count as bard spells for you *and are included in the number in the Spells Known column in the Bard table.* (PHB p.54, emphasis mine)

So magical secrets gives you a broader *choice* of spells; the total *number* of spells is 22.

Answer (score 11):

They have 22. The entry for Magical Secrets states that the extra two spells that you 'plunder' are included in the 'spells known' column.

A College of Lore bard will have 24 bard spells known, with their Additional Magical Secrets.